# jest and enzyme: how to test component with useContext()

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I need to test the following component (basically I want to test for the presence of the App component when the username and refresh token are present):

```
const ParentRouter = () => {
  const { username, refreshToken } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return (
    <Switch data-test="component-ParentRouter">
      {console.log("test1")}
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={LoginPage} />
      {console.log("test2")}
      <ProtectedRoute
        isAllowed={refreshToken}
        username={username}
        path="/"
        component={App}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
const TestProtectedRouteWithCredentials = () => (
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/ProjectsOverview/"]}>
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        username: "testUser1",
        refreshToken: "hfsjkadhfjkshdfjkshdafs"
      }}
    >
      <ParentRouter />
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  </MemoryRouter>
);

test("if userame and props then allow redirect to protected route i.e. app", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TestProtectedRouteWithCredentials />);
  expect(
    wrapper
      .find(ParentRouter)
      .dive()
      .find(App)
  ).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

I can't seem to get it working though.

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `username` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

I've had a search around but not really found what I'm looking for. If anyone can show me a decent way to test this component using Jest and Enzyme I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2176) about `useContext()` not working with enzyme shallow. Try to use `mount` instead.

If you don't want to use mount, you can try to mock your GlobalContext as a workaround. Here's [an article](https://medium.com/7shifts-engineering-blog/testing-usecontext-react-hook-with-enzyme-shallow-da062140fc83) explaining how you can do it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when using `mount`: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usecontext-jest-test-9r93g?file=/src/Component.spec.js